# Grails: How to configure lock_timeout with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, grails, datasource

The H2 database in Grails that is set up by default in `Datasource.groovy` looks something like:

```
url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
```

Configuring `LOCK_TIMEOUT` is done by means of the jdbc url.

I have code using a Postgresql datasource that appears to have a deadlock issue and I'd like to set `LOCK_TIMEOUT` for it.  How do you do this for a postgresql datasource please?  It doesn't work if you put the `LOCK_TIMEOUT` value in the url.

Comment: you can set it in transaction by SET deadlock_timeout statement in SQL sourse itself

Comment: OK, but how does that work in Grails when using GORM / Hibernate and not using SQL directly?